# mongoDB: Unable to obtain full object response when reference exists in the object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query an object using `find`.
the whole object is like so

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60d9"),
"invoiceItems" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "JobsPostings",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5aad26b6f78a341ef831b4f7"),
        "price" : 15,
        "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60db")
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "JobsPostings",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5aad27e4f78a341ef831b513"),
        "price" : 20,
        "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60da")
    }
  ], 
  {...}
}
```

and I am trying to fetch invoiceItems object which is:

```
"invoiceItems" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "JobsPostings",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5aad26b6f78a341ef831b4f7"),
        "price" : 15,
        "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60db")
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "JobsPostings",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5aad27e4f78a341ef831b513"),
        "price" : 20,
        "publishDate" : ISODate("2018-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60da")
    }
]
```

Here is my code for fetching:

```
PostPaidInvoice.find({_id: { $in : [ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60d9")]}}).then(result => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].invoiceItems));
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

The response I receive does not include results of `price` and `publishDate`:

```
[{"_bsontype":"DBRef","namespace":"JobsPostings","oid":"5aad26b6f78a341ef831b4f7"},{"_bsontype":"DBRef","namespace":"JobsPostings","oid":"5aad27e4f78a341ef831b513"}]
```

But if I remove the dollar sign ($) from the reference `ref` then it returns the whole object.

Comment: Its because, your document is invalid. According to mongodb documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names, field name cannot start with `$`.

Comment: @RaKa No, it is a dbref relation so we store that like this.

Comment: @Raka you should see this page as a reference [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add just one key `invoiceItems: 1` just after find condition:

```
PostPaidInvoice.find({
  _id: {
      $in: [ObjectId("5aaf4133b72ed853c09d60d9")]
  }
 }, { invoiceItems: 1, _id: 0 }).then(result => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].invoiceItems));
 }).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```